# How to get Values to a page where the page opens after clicking on Hyper link

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two pages in which I used GridView in one page.In GridView I used Hyperlink to open second page after clicking on it. I am passing the values in Hyperlink which i want to use in second page.

Here is my code

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
     NavigateUrl='<%# "db_PmuKpi_OBPI_AllPMs.aspx?PMRMId="+ Eval("PMRMID") + "&sRM =" + 
                  Eval("PMRMName")%>' Text='<%# Eval("PMRMName","{0}")%>' />
<asp:Label ID="lblRM" runat="server" />
```

I want to use PMRMID and PMRMName in second page .How to I get them

Answer (score 2):

Use Request.QueryString to retrive the values passed in the url.

```
Request.QueryString["PMRMId"]
```

Check this for detail:

[HttpRequest.QueryString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I used Request.QueryString but unable to get values

Comment: string sRMID = Request.QueryString["PMRMID"]; I used this

Comment: Use string sRMID = Request.QueryString["PMRMId"];

Comment: Use PMRMId as key to retrive value instead of PMRMID

Comment: Yes...Before its my Typo.I used PMRMId only

Comment: What url you get when you click on gridview link.

Comment: url is same as what I have given in Hyperlink..In the Url I can see the PMRMId and PMRMName Values also

Comment: Hi Got it..In MY Hyperlink I am using PMRMID..which is already used in BoundField